# gwt Using safehtml in window.settitle for setting browser title

Tags: gwt, xss

I need to send a SafeHtml to Window.setTitle().
The problem is that i use SafeHtmlUtils.fromString(String c) on the title.
Due to chance of XSS Leaks.

The result is that i get a bad looking title (due to the conversion SafeHtmlUtils.fromString to HTML Entity References)

My question is can you set the Window title with a SafeHtml?
Or how do i convert the Safehtml back to normal String?

code (updated):

```java
    public void setTitle(SafeHtml title) {
            internalHeader.setPageTitle(title);
        Window.setTitle(("fileee | " + title).replaceAll("\\<.*?>", ""));

    }


//in internalHeader
    public void setPageTitle(SafeHtml title) {
        pageNameBig.setInnerSafeHtml(title);

    }
```

pageNameBig is a HeadingElement.
Problem is that if i put in `<h1>test` the result is in Window.setTitle = `&lt;h1&gt;test`

but in the internalHeader is good = dispalys `<h1>test`

Is all because of its HTML Entity References.

Comment: What you mean by bad looking title ? Can you post an example ?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible for XSS on the title of the window because the title can't render HTML.

`SafeHtml.asString()` will get you a string, though not the original from `SafeHtmlUtils.fromStrong` - instead, since the window title can't display any HTML, there is no need to use SafeHtml at all.

Comment: I updated, the problem is that i have an internal header as well that i try use the safehtml for. the result is <h1> = &lt;h1&gt;